# Cannot properly see a comment I'm adding with Firefox for Android

Tags: bug, comments

On Firefox for Android, when I try to add a comment, the bottom half of the text is hidden. And stuff like punctuations cannot be seen at all.

[image: Firefox for Android comment box]

It works better in Google Chrome, however, so the issue seems exclusive to Firefox. 
[image: Chrome for Android comment box]

Comment: hope there isn't the same issue with the app :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now. The comment box is much better and bigger in both browsers, Firefox and Chrome.

[image]